Android USB prompt every time connecting to USB after installing Spacedesk
Since installing Spacedesk on my Android 14 phone, a prompt showed up every time it's connected to USB asking if I wanted to open Spacedesk. Since uninstalling the app, this prompt is showed up
"No installed app works with this USB accessory..."

I reset some settings related to USB and even apps with no success. Disabled Android Auto and still no success. Googling and AI didn't help either. How should I get rid of that?

Time to factory reset the phone.

Welcome to Super User! Please read the tags before posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].
